# List of kicked/banned users in a Telegram group/channel using telethon

Tags: telegram, telethon

With `telethon` you can do pretty much anything you want around Telegram. However, I cannot find a way to get a list of removed (banned) users in a group/channel. Any ideas?

For the record, you can do that via Telegram's GUI by going to `Edit > Permissions > Removed Users`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get a list of all the removed users in a Telegram group/channel using Telethon you need to use [`get_participants()`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.chats.ChatMethods.get_participants) with `filter` parameter set to [`ChannelParticipantsKicked`](https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/channel_participants_kicked.html).

```
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsKicked # import type to use as filter
kicked_members = await client.get_participants(chat, filter=ChannelParticipantsKicked)
```

If you'd prefer to loop over the result without assign it to a variable you can use [`iter_participants()`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.chats.ChatMethods.iter_participants) instead.

```
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsKicked 
async for user in client.iter_participants(chat, filter=ChannelParticipantsKicked):
    print(user.first_name)
```

NR: here is a list of all the avaible [`filters`](https://tl.telethon.dev/types/channel_participants_filter.html) usable with `get/iter_participants()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern="/[Bb]anlist",from_users=admin))
async def banlist(event):
  text = (event.raw_text).split(" ")
  try:
    bans = await  client.get_participants(text[1] , filter=ChannelParticipantsKicked)
    ban_list = ""
    for i in bans:
      if (i.username != None):
        ban_list += "@" + i.username +'\n'
    await event.reply("BAN LSIT: {}".format(ban_list))
  except:
    await event.reply("ERROR!")
```

Comment: Suggestion : add code fences and the language identifier to highlight the code and make it more readable.